# Is there a way to convert a standard text file to a csv file

Tags: pandas, text, datatable, jupyter-notebook

I have a batch of text that I am trying to convert into a table. The beginning lines of the file begins as shown below and the last bracket shows the data that I need to obtain. I am trying to break up the information in the brackets into a column with the text before the "=" as the header and the information in the quotes as the data. The issue I'm running into is that it is a text file and I'm unsure of how to edit the text file to delete the first 6 lines and then convert the remaining data into csv type data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XML version="3.0">
<AccountProvider name="Investments Int" code="IB">
<Imports/>
<InterpretFXRates/>
<PSXList date="20201207" batch="3">
<PSX portfolio="11111111" trancode="c1" type1="c2" iso1="c3" symbol1="c4" trade="20201207">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the first six lines after reading the file, convert the content to a dataframe and write to a csv:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('file.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()[6:]

content = [x.strip()[1:-1].replace('" ', '",').replace('"', '') for x in content]  # drop <>, make comma-separated, and remove " marks

res = [dict(item.split("=") for item in strn.split(',')) for strn in content]

df = pd.DataFrame(res)

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

This works for when there are more than one entry lines as well.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it should work. However, I'm running into the following error on line 9 with the res = ...: 
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #16 has length 1; 2 is required
Any ideas?

Comment: This error would be thrown if one of the comma-separated terms is missing the =. I copied the text you have to a txt file and it run fine on my machine.  Are you running on the same text as here? Or you may share the actual txt file.